# LINQ on System.Object (type known only at runtime using reflection)

Tags: linq, reflection

I have a simlar requirement where in i have 3 main entities in ADO.NET entity model... I am building a framework wherein basedon incoming XML root element i have to create an instance of specific entity using reflection and set its properties..

But when it comes to child entities.. I am not able to use LINQ queries on it as the type is not known at design time. PropertyInfo.GetValue gives me an object on which i can not run LINQ queries (even when i typecast it to IQueryable or IEnumerable). I am not even able to typecast it at design time as that would be kind of hardcoding and will fail my generic framework purpose.

I tried to use dynamic keyword.. but on that too i can not write LINQ queries.. it gives a message that LINQ queries are not supported on dynamic dispatch model.!!!

Can someone help..

Regards Badal

Comment: I haven't used it in a long time, but [Dynamic LINQ](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Dynamic-LINQ.aspx) may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Yuriy Faktorovich recommended, dynamic LINQ may be your best shot.

**Another option** you have is to dynamically build **[expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)** and execute your expression via reflection.  Keep in mind that this is not easy and may take a little time to wrap your head around the expression API, but for simple expression it's not too bad.

Example: Say you want to replicate this expression:

```
p => p.FirstName == firstName
```

You can build the expression tree as follows:

```
var myType = Type.GetType("Person"); // <-- Find your type based on XML
var firstName = "John";

var param = Expression.Parameter(myType, "p");
var firstNameProperty = Expression.Property(param, "FirstName");
var constantExpression = Expression.Constant(firstName);
var equalsExpression = Expression.Equal(firstNameProperty, constantExpression);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda(equalsExpression, param);
```

The lambda will have a runtime type of `Expression<Func<Person,bool>>` which you can then pass to any `IQueryable` implementation.

**UPDATE**

Then to dynamcially call some method on your `IQueryable` you can do something similar to the following:

```
var queryableType = typeof(Queryable);
var whereMethod = queryableType.GetMethod("Where", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

var parameters = new object[] { query, lambda }; // query is your IQueryable object
var list = whereMethod.Invoke(null, parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Looks like this can solve my problem.. but I did not understand this part of your comment

The lambda will have a runtime type of Expression<Func<Person,bool>> which you can then pass to any IQueryable implementation

My next question is .. how do i execute this lambda expression and get the desired output?

Regards
Badal

Comment: The problem is i do not now type T of IQueryable<T> at design time.. and i can not hardcode the typecasting and hence not able to apply "Where" method and passing this lambda expression to it. I get an object using reflection from entity model (PropertyInfo.GetValue()) whose runtime type is ObjectSet<entity> if i do the typecasting at design time.. I am able to query.. but how do i do that at rutime? as soon as i write the from prop in objet Where or object.Where(nc => nc.id == primaryKey).. it bombs... as it does not find Where implementation.

Regards
Badal

Comment: I think you will need to dynamically call your `Where` on your `ObjectSet<T>` using reflection.  At that point you can pass it the expression tree that you constructed using my example.

Comment: @Badal Kotecha - I've updated my answer to include an example on how to call `Where` method on your IQueryable.